# Save PDF automatically on exit in Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, automation, adobe-reader, prompt

Adobe Reader prompts me to save on exit.

This is an operation I do several times a day every day, so if I Adobe Reader could just save my changes without asking me (that is, comments), that would be great.

Comment: I don't have Adobe Reader (btw. which version exactly do you use?), but [this Adobe article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/AutoSaveDocs.html) says: Set `Preferences > Documents > Save Settings > Automatically save document changes` to *Auto save documents.*. At the same menu, set `minutes text field` to 1. Your document will be saved every minute. That's not perfect, since it is not immediatly. But it's a start.

Comment: I Use the latest version, Adobe Reader XI 11.0.07. That does not solve the problem. That setting only saves a temporary file for recovery purposes, not the actual file.

If Adobe Reader at least could work like most other programs - just _one_ prompt, not multiple. As it is now, it not only 1) prompts you if you want to save the changes, you also have to 2) go through the save as dialog box (one enter press is enough though), and 3) another prompt where it asks you if you want to overwrite the file, where "no" is the default answer.

Way too many key presses for me, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Changing my preferences to "Preferences > Documents > Save Settings > Automatically save document changes" helped this popup stop appearing on every single document for me.